# Extracing JSON from syslog-pefixed lines in C#

Tags: c#, json, parsing, syslog

I'm trying to parse a syslog (or syslog-like) response to extract only the JSON

```
<14>1 09 30 2019 15:34:37 UTC logsource {"somejson": "thejson", "details": {"detail1": detail, "detail2": detail"}}

<14>1 09 30 2019 15:34:37 UTC logsource {"somejson": "thejson", "details": {"detail1": detail, "detail2": detail"}}

<14>1 09 30 2019 15:34:37 UTC logsource {"somejson": "thejson", "details": {"detail1": detail, "detail2": detail"}}
```

I would like to remove the "<14>1 09 30 2019 15:34:37 UTC logsource" prefix so that the remaining data is a valid JSON so I can send each line to a database. I figure the output would look something like this:

```
{
    "body" [
        {
            "somejson": "thejson",
            "details": {
                "detail1": details,
                "detail2": details.
            }
        },
        {
            "somejson": "thejson",
            "details": {
                "detail1": details,
                "detail2": details.
            }
        },
        {
            "somejson": "thejson",
            "details": {
                "detail1": details,
                "detail2": details.
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Perhaps I could loop through the original data and replace the string using String.Replace somehow? I appreciate any help even if it's jut pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I assume the "<14>1 09 30 2019 15:34:37 UTC logsource" will not be consistent?  so what you need to do, if I understand, is remove everything before the first "{".  is that correct?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Yes, removing everything before the first { would be ideal. Presumably to make this a valid JSON, I would also need to add in some formatting as well

Comment: Removing everything before the first { is very simple. You can figure that out with a quick google search like `c# remove everything before character`. From there is should be easy to add the opening `{"body" [` and closing `]}`

Comment: @CaseyCrookston I don't think I would have a problem removing something from a short string but how would I remove everything before the first { in each line starting with <14>? I'm a bit lost at being able to loop through each line and do that same action

Comment: Ok, it sounds like there is something going on here that you maybe didn't explain in your post. Do you have a `List<string>` in which you need to modify each string in the list? Also, in the sample you showed us, is this the entire content of the string?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to using Newtonsoft.Json. You can parse the string into a `JObject` after you have cut away the log prefix that you don't need. I also went ahead and removed the blank lines in your input. Here is the code that I used to do this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace extractingJSONSyslogQuestion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
            var lines = input.Split("\n");

            // Remove blank lines
            lines = lines.Where(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l)).ToArray();

            foreach(var line in lines) {
                // Get rid of log prefix
                var data = line.Substring(line.IndexOf("{"));
                var json = JObject.Parse(data);
                Console.WriteLine(json);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the input file that I used. Notice that I added double quotes around the string "detail" to make it valid json:

```
<14>1 09 30 2019 15:34:37 UTC logsource {"somejson": "thejson", "details": {"detail1": "detail", "detail2": "detail"}}

<14>1 09 30 2019 15:34:37 UTC logsource {"somejson": "thejson", "details": {"detail1": "detail", "detail2": "detail"}}

<14>1 09 30 2019 15:34:37 UTC logsource {"somejson": "thejson", "details": {"detail1": "detail", "detail2": "detail"}
```

Finally, here is the output from my program:

```
{
  "somejson": "thejson",
  "details": {
    "detail1": "detail",
    "detail2": "detail"
  }
}
{
  "somejson": "thejson",
  "details": {
    "detail1": "detail",
    "detail2": "detail"
  }
}
{
  "somejson": "thejson",
  "details": {
    "detail1": "detail",
    "detail2": "detail"
  }
}
```

I am happy to answer any questions about the code in more detail if you leave a comment.